# Java - Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?

Tags: java, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

So I have read through the other threads regarding this and have not found a solution.

The problem Im having is because im setting "access-control-allow-methods" "true" I cant use `setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

I need to set two specific domains...any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class CorsInterceptor implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {
        //When we send the http-only cookie the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header cannot be *
        responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", requestContext.getHeaderString("origin"));
    }
}
```

Comment: warning: this answer allows *any* origins.

Comment: Equivalent to using '*'. Just not directly using it

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
private static final String URL = "http://somehost:port"; // URL
private static final String OTHER_URL = "http://otherhost:port"; // OTHER URL  

private void setAccessControlAllowOrigin(HttpServletResponse response,
     HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (URL.equals(request.getHeader("Origin"))) {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", URL);
    } else if (OTHER_URL.equals(request.getHeader("Origin"))) {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", OTHER_URL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things: if you want to format a code block, then there's a specific button in the editor just for that; you don't need to surround everything with a backtick. Second, when you post an answer that consists entirely of code, especially an answer to a question that was asked a long time ago, please be sure to explain why your solution is better than the other answers already provided.

Comment: this solved my problem, which was similar to the one that was originally asked: allow two differrent origins. one problem not clearly mentioned here is that especially in `GET` requests, the server should check the origin header for validity before processing the request, as otherwise the result is only rejected in the browser, which may result in unwanted side effects - but then again, requests resulting in side effects should not have the `GET` method in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to modify your http method to :

```
 public Response getYourMethod( HttpServletRequest request) 
                             throws Exception, IOException{
  //then your code
 }
```

Now after that add the following:

Since your API looks for `www.yoursite.com:3000` in the Allow Origin Header, you need to make sure this is getting added in the following line:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "www.yoursite.com:3000");
```

To get the `www.yoursite.com:3000` you can use :

```
String requestUrl = request.getRemoteAddr() + ":" + request.getRemotePort();
```

But if the browser looks for localhost then go for the :

```
request.getRemoteHost().
```

So you can basically have something like this:

```
if (requestUrl.equals(yourAPIURL)){
   //allow access
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", requestUrl);
}
```

Avoid adding `*` because some browsers and API will not still allow that and can be rejected by preflight requests, if you are using a browser.

Make sure that you add the headers and methods properly as mentioned in the post.

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: ???  I already know how to set the url.  Im saying I need to be able to set two specific URL's

Comment: @DocHoliday Yes, then use `request.getRemoteAddr() + ":" + request.getRemotePort()`;

Comment: If the above string matches your url then allow the request else reject it.

Comment: I need to get the origin domain name.  that is just giving me the Client IP

Comment: @DocHoliday You can use `request.getRemoteHost()`

Comment: None of those are working.  Just Ip addresses are coming thru

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121108/discussion-between-pritam-banerjee-and-doc-holiday).

Comment: `request.getRemoteHost()` will not work in this context, as it returns the client's or the last proxy's address, whereas the `origin` should be the protocol/host/port part of the referrer. isee also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach to allow only specific origins

1. Define a property in `.properties` file to get the value for allowing origins as follow

```
#CORS Settings
cors.origins.allowed=https://127.0.0.1:5500, http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

Implement a Filter class where we can modify the response allow origin header

```
private String setAllowedOrigin(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String requestOrigin = request.getHeader("origin");
        log.info("Request is received with origin header : {}", requestOrigin);
        List<String> originsList = Arrays.stream(this.origins.split(","))
                .map(String::trim).filter(origin -> !origin.equals("")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        log.info("origins List : {}", originsList);
        if (!originsList.isEmpty() && requestOrigin != null) {
            Optional<String> origin = originsList.stream().filter(allowedOrigin -> allowedOrigin.equals(requestOrigin)).findFirst();
            return origin.orElseGet(() -> originsList.get(0));
        }
        return "*";
    }


 @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", setAllowedOrigin(request));
       
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

This CORS filter allows only origins mentioned in properties files only
To illustrate the behaviour, I used  Visual studio code live server with the following code I have a `test` endpoint in my API.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <Script>
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/test", { method: "get" })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data));
    </Script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Sample Image when I hit the live server]