# Enabling Cross Origin Requests for WebSockets in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I have a OpenShift Wildfly server. I am building a website with the `Spring MVC` framework. One of my webpages also uses a WebSocket connection. On the server side, I have used the `@ServerEndpoint` annotation and `javax.websocket.*` library to create my websocket:

```
package com.myapp.spring.web.controller;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.SpringConfigurator;


@ServerEndpoint(value="/serverendpoint", configurator = SpringConfigurator.class)

public class serverendpoint {

    @OnOpen
    public void handleOpen () {
        System.out.println("JAVA: Client is now connected...");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String handleMessage (Session session, String message) throws IOException {

        if (message.equals("ping")) {
//            return "pong"
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText("pong");
        }
        else if (message.equals("close")) {
            handleClose();
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("JAVA: Received from client: "+ message);
        MyClass mc = new MyClass(message);
        String res = mc.action();
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText(res);
        return res;
    }

    @OnClose
    public void handleClose() {
        System.out.println("JAVA: Client is now disconnected...");
    }

    @OnError
    public void handleError (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

OpenShift gives a default URL, so all of my webpages (html files) have the common (canonical) hostname. For the sake of simplicity, I am calling this URL `URL A` (**`projectname-domainname.rhclound.com`**). I created an alias, CNAME, of `URL A`, which is called `URL B` (say **`https://www.mywebsite.tech`**). `URL B` is secure, as it has the `https`.

I am using a JavaScript client to connect to the WebSocket at the path `/serverendpoint`. The URI I am using in my html webpage file, `test.html`, is the following:

```
var wsUri = "wss://" + "projectname-domainname.rhclound.com" + ":8443" + "/serverendpoint";
```

When I open up `URL A` (**`projectname-domainname.rhclound.com/test`**), the WebSocket connects and everything works fine. However, when I try to connect to the websocket using `URL B` (**`https://mywebsite.tech/test`**), the JavaScript client immediately connects and disconnects.

Here is the message from the console that I receive:

[image]

Here is my JavaScript code that connects to the WebSocket:

```
/****** BEGIN WEBSOCKET ******/
            var connectedToWebSocket = false;
            var responseMessage = '';
            var webSocket = null;
            function initWS() {
                connectedToWebSocket = false;
                var wsUri = "wss://" + "projectname-domainname.rhcloud.com" + ":8443" + "/serverendpoint";
                webSocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); // Create a new instance of WebSocket using usUri
                webSocket.onopen = function(message) {
                    processOpen(message);
                };
                webSocket.onmessage = function(message) {
                    responseMessage = message.data;
                    if (responseMessage !== "pong") { // Ping-pong messages to keep a persistent connection between server and client
                        processResponse(responseMessage);
                    }
                    return false;
                };
                webSocket.onclose = function(message) {
                    processClose(message);
                };
                webSocket.onerror = function(message) {
                    processError(message);
                };
                console.log("Exiting initWS()");
            }

            initWS(); //Connect to websocket

            function processOpen(message) {
                connectedToWebSocket = true;
                console.log("JS: Server Connected..."+message);
            }

            function sendMessage(toServer) { // Send message to server
                if (toServer != "close") {
                    webSocket.send(toServer);
                } else {
                    webSocket.close();
                }
            }

            function processClose(message) {
                connectedToWebSocket = false;
                console.log("JS: Client disconnected..."+message);
            }

            function processError(message) { 
                userInfo("An error occurred. Please contact for assistance", true, true);
            }
            setInterval(function() {
                if (connectedToWebSocket) {
                    webSocket.send("ping");
                }
            }, 4000); // Send ping-pong message to server
/****** END WEBSOCKET ******/
```

After a lot of debugging and trying various things, I concluded that this was problem was occurring because of the Spring Framework. **This is because before I introduced the `Spring Framework` in my project, `URL B` could connect to the WebSocket, but after introducing Spring, it cannot.**
I read on [spring's website](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/websocket.html) about WebSocket Policy. I came across their [same origin policy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-sameorigin) which states that an alias, `URL B`, cannot connect to the WebSocket because it is not the same origin as `URL A` is. To solve this problem I [disabled the same origin policy with WebSockets](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-sameorigin-disable) as said in the documentation, so I added the following code. I thought that doing so would fix my error. Here is what I added:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

However, this did not fix the problem, so I added the following method to my `ApplicationConfig` which `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("https://www.mywebsite.com");
}
```

This also didn't work either. Then I tried this:

```
package com.myapp.spring.security.config;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

@Configuration
public class MyCorsFilter {

//  @Bean
//  public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
//      System.out.println("Filchain");
//      UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
//      CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
//      config.setAllowCredentials(true);
//      config.addAllowedOrigin("https://www.mymt.tech");
//      config.addAllowedHeader("*");
//      config.addAllowedMethod("*");
//      source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
//      FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
//      bean.setOrder(0);
//      System.out.println("Filchain");
//      return bean;
//  }

     @Bean
     public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
         System.out.println("Filchain");
         UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
         CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
         config.setAllowCredentials(true); // you USUALLY want this
         config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
         config.addAllowedHeader("*");
         config.addAllowedMethod("*");
         config.addAllowedMethod("*");
         source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
         System.out.println("Filchain");
         return new CorsFilter(source);
     }

}
```

This also did not work.

I even changed the `var wsURI` in the JS code to the following: 
`var wsUri = "wss://" + "www.mywebsite.com" + ":8443" + "/serverendpoint";`
Then `var wsUri = "wss://" + "mywebsite.com" + ":8443" + "/serverendpoint";`

When I did this, the Google Chrome gave me an error, saying that the handshake failed. However, when I have this URL, `var wsUri = "wss://" + "projectname-domianname.rhcloud.com" + ":8443" + "/serverendpoint";`, I did not get the error that the handshake didn't occur, but I get a message that the connection opened and closed immediately (as seen above).

So how can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried to make the websocket local to url b? just to test it connects at all

Comment: Look at this documentation

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: If your backend and frontend exists on the same you can leverage proxying: there no cross origin resource sharing happening that way.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried implementing the `WebMvcConfigurer` and overriding the method `addCorsMappings()`? If not try this and see.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("*")
        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST")
        .allowedHeaders("Origin", "Accept", "Content-Type", "Authorization")
        .allowCredentials(true)
        .maxAge(3600);

    }

}
```

Comment: Warning, this can allow all the origins, Please check this answer to how we can restrict the origins. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983949/java-access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains/67665523#67665523

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a CORS issue because it's connected successully before being disconnected. If that's CORS, you can't even connect.

I think it's a communication problem between your DNS & openshift because WebSocket need a persistent connection (long-live) which keeps opening between client & server. If your DNS (e.g. CloudFlare or something like that) does not support / not configured to use WebSocket, the client would be disconnected immediately as in your issue.